# 'unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4' thrown by MariaDB stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

We have a stored procedure in MariaDB that runs fine on the server, however when we run it from a client with JDBC we get the first rows but later it always fails with:

```
unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)
```

The table `loan_balances2` is not too big, around 600K rows.  This is the stored procedure, do you see any issues? thanks!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_loan_balances_sample`()

BEGIN

drop table if exists all_loan_ids;
drop table if exists random_loan_ids;

create table all_loan_ids as select distinct loan_id from loan_balances2;
create table random_loan_ids as select * from all_loan_ids order by RAND() limit 50;

SELECT * FROM loan_balances2
where loan_id in (select Loan_ID from random_loan_ids)
order by Loan_ID, balance_date;

END
```

Comment: Changing wait_timeout maybe [like this answer](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/migrating-from-mysql-mariadb-server-closing-client-connections-unexpectedly/).

Comment: @danblack changing `wait_timeout` didn't help

Comment: [max_allowed_packet](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_allowed_packet) - increase? (i'm not sure why it would be different in a procedure however). Which MariaDB version?

Comment: No, that doesn't work either. I think the issue here is not the client timeout or packet size, the issue is that for whatever reason the server closes the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually [net_write_timeout](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#net_write_timeout) . Server closes the socket, if your application is not reading data as fast as the server writes them. net_write_timeout defines, in seconds, how long server can stuck trying to send the result set. You can increase that limit, it is a session variable. This also appears in the MariaDB JDBC's  [FAQ](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#error-could-not-read-resultset-unexpected-end-of-stream-read-0-bytes-from-4)